# Insert image in Magento CMS error

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload, cms-block, cms-pages

When we try to insert the image in cms page or cms block the popup not showing any images which we have uploaded as well as no button for upload image.
Please check below image:

[image]

Comment: Check the media folder permission.

Comment: check the flash player install in browser

Comment: @SukumarGorai permission is 755

Comment: @JigsParmar flash player is already installed

Comment: are you able to add product iamges??

Comment: @JigsParmar yes problem is only with when I insert images in cms page and static block